# C# Serialization Unknow issue

Tags: c#, serialization

Hello i try to seriliaze a file but i have a very
strange problem.

At first saving, all variable are serialized correctly.
Next, many variables remain empty others are saved.

1° Serialization code

```
   public void SaveMireProject(string projectName,string root_path)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();

            using (FileStream _FileStream =
                    new FileStream(root_path + "\\" + projectName + ".mireprj", System.IO.FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                //bin.Serialize(_FileStream, this);

                bin.Serialize(_FileStream, Tiles);
                bin.Serialize(_FileStream, project_name);
                bin.Serialize(_FileStream, root_directory);
                try { bin.Serialize(_FileStream, project_pat); } catch { }
                try { bin.Serialize(_FileStream, project_type); } catch { }
                bin.Serialize(_FileStream, Events);
                bin.Serialize(_FileStream, Light);
                bin.Serialize(_FileStream, StartupMap);
                bin.Serialize(_FileStream, startX);
                bin.Serialize(_FileStream, startY);
                _FileStream.Close();
                _FileStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

2° Deserilization Code

```
 public void OpenProject(string filename)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                Tiles = (List<_Tiles>)bin.Deserialize(fs);
                project_name = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs);
                root_directory = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs);

                try { Events = (List<_ev>)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { Events = new List<_ev>(); };

                try { Light = (List<_light>)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { Light = new List<_light>(); };

                try { project_pat = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { };
                try { project_type = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { };

                try { StartupMap = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { };
                try { startX = (int)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { }
                try { startY = (int)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { }

            }

        }
```

Some of the important variables are as

StartupMap, startX and startY.

after set value to the variabile,
i see whit debugger, all value are stored.

[image]

i set breakpoint to save line.
and i see value are in the variabile

next, i try to open now file serialized,
and i see this

[image]

breakpoint set after the OpenProject Method are called.

anyone know what are the problem?

Comment: You're not reading the variables in the same order you're writing them.

Comment: Don't do try/catches each element, when one element could not be (de)serialized, it will go out of sync. A file can be deserialized or not

Comment: At first try to remove all `catch { }`. You clearly making self blind with them.

Comment: ok i try to remove all try catch

Answer (score 2):

you serialize

```
 try { bin.Serialize(_FileStream, project_pat); } catch { }
 try { bin.Serialize(_FileStream, project_type); } catch { }
 bin.Serialize(_FileStream, Events);
 bin.Serialize(_FileStream, Light);
```

and you deserialize like :

```
try { Events = (List<_ev>)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { Events = new List<_ev>(); };
try { Light = (List<_light>)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { Light = new List<_light>(); };
try { project_pat = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { };
try { project_type = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs); } catch { };
```

the sequence of serialize and deserialize is not correct you cannot put try catch also, because if some failure serialize and deserialize on each item, will change orders...

try serlize like :

```
bin.Serialize(_FileStream, Tiles);
bin.Serialize(_FileStream, project_name);
bin.Serialize(_FileStream, root_directory);
bin.Serialize(_FileStream, project_pat); 
bin.Serialize(_FileStream, project_type);
bin.Serialize(_FileStream, Events);
bin.Serialize(_FileStream, Light);
bin.Serialize(_FileStream, StartupMap);
bin.Serialize(_FileStream, startX);
bin.Serialize(_FileStream, startY);
```

and deserialize like :

```
Tiles = (List<_Tiles>)bin.Deserialize(fs);
project_name = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs);
root_directory = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs);
project_pat = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs);
project_type = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs); 
Events = (List<_ev>)bin.Deserialize(fs);
Light = (List<_light>)bin.Deserialize(fs);
StartupMap = (string)bin.Deserialize(fs);
startX = (int)bin.Deserialize(fs);
startY = (int)bin.Deserialize(fs);
```

with correct order

Comment: Tanks Emran but now i have a new problem.
file not are saved. i have set breakpoint to SaveMireProject method, 
the new file dont are saved. old file are present...

Comment: make sure you do not have put SaveMireProject in try catch method, may be that try catch will capture exception

Comment: And more one problem. Plase see the screen and red rectangle whit breakpoint.
https://s27.postimg.org/p6or1txtv/screen.png